# PHP session with UTF-8-BOM encoding

Tags: php, utf-8

I have created one php page with UTF-8-BOM encoding. I want to use this encoding because I have some content which are in my regional language, and do display it properly i need to use UTF-8-BOM encoding.

Now I want to use session with this page but it is throwing error of headers already set.

So is there any way i can use both together.

If I am trying to use UTF-8 only I am not getting problem displaying data in regional format.

[See Attached Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJOUT.jpg)

Comment: No code no help possible

Comment: Try UTF-8 without BOM

Comment: @hisener with UTF-8 without BOM I am getting error in displaying data. I have attached screenshot for same in my main post

Comment: @MikeMiller I am not sure what kind of code i should pest here.

Comment: The code that is causing the error would make sense

Comment: @MikeMiller : before getting data from database I am using this query mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'"); and as I have just encoded my PHP with UTF-8-BOM it is working fine. But when I am using session I am just writing SESSION_START() at top of page but it is giving me error of "headers are already set".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Byte Order Mark" is a sequence of 3 bytes that a file begins with, making it pretty much incompatible with PHP, because a script that is supposed to contain *only* PHP code must start with the `<?php` tag instead.

Obviously, it's not like the whole thing doesn't work at all, but anything that involves sending HTTP headers (which is A LOT) automatically gets broken.

Sessions use cookies - transferred via headers - won't work.
Redirecting to another page - the `Location` header - won't work.
Dynamically generated downloads - the downloaded file itself will be broken.

etc.

Sorry, but you'll have to give up on BOM and figure another way to handle your locale-specific data (which I can only assume is using another charset for whatever reason).

Comment: Thanks for updating.